# How can I load an empty object into a dictionary from appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, .net-6.0

I'm trying to load values into a custom options class on app startup in C#/.net6. Some of the input from `appsettings.json` is not being loaded as I would like.

My options class looks like this:

```
    public class CustomOptions
    {
        
        public Dictionary<string, CustomInfo> MyOptions { get; set; }
        
    }

    public class CustomInfo
    {

        public Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryField { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public List<string> ListField { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
```

and `appsettings.json` contains the following:

```json
"CustomOptions" : {
    "MyOptions": {
      "OptionOne": {},
      "OptionTwo": {
        "DictionaryField": {
          "ValueOne": "somevalue",
          "ValueTwo": "someothervalue"
        },
        "ListField": [
          "ListItem"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

and loading the options in Program.cs with

```
builder.Services.AddOptions<EndpointOptions>().Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(EndpointOptions.Key));
```

As it stands, OptionTwo is loaded correctly with all fields set, yet OptionOne does not even appear in the injected `IOptions<TOptions>` service.

What I would like is for OptionOne to be loaded into the `MyOptions` dict with a default `CustomInfo` object or null value. Is this possible?

**Edit:** I need to be able to add more options beyond OptionOne and OptionTwo at some point, and ideally would be able to do this through `appsettings.json`, hence the need for a dictionary in `MyOptions` class. All these options will still follow the CustomInfo class.

Answer (score 2):

The [`JsonConfigurationFileParser`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8604989022950ef38f94b9150043b31d81f061a5/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/src/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs#L47) ignores any empty object and simply add value of `null` as configuration value, that is ignored [during binding](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/135053eae07c2bcf21d73996aaca19daae8f9323/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L338).

If you really need both options to be added to the dictionary, you could add at least one property to `OptionOne` section:

```
"OptionOne": {
  "DictionaryField": {}
}
```

Frankly, in the sense of low memory allocating, it makes sense to not create an empty instance of `CustomInfo`, but use the `TryGetValue` method on dictionary to test if the value exists.